# Using the Overlay feature in panel but showing only an averaged line

Tags: overlay, stata

I have created an overlay of 100 curves. I thought the image looked impressive but one of my reviewers stated that I should only show the averaged line. Meaning, only show a line that is the average of the 100 curves. Is this possible using the `xtline` feature, or do I need to get deeper into programming code to produce the graphic? Alternatively, it would be great if I could show both (the 100 curves and the averaged curve) in the same graphic.

Comment: without any code or data, we have no way of knowing how to advise. If you could give us some kind of example then we will be able to help

Comment: I agree with @EricHB that this is a poor question without any attempt at code or data example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the standard here.

Comment: I didn't actually have an error of any sort. The question was more about "can I" than it was about "I got this error message".  I read through the "How to create.." guidance and I think that would have been information overload. However, thanks to the both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything complicated here. Just calculate the mean across the panel and show it directly. Here is some technique. I am guessing that in your real example with 100 curves a legend is pointless. Note the `c(L)` and read the help to find what it does.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
set scheme s1color 
gen log_invest = log(invest)
egen mean_log_invest = mean(log_invest), by(year)
line log_invest year, legend(off) lc(gs12)  c(L) || line mean_log_invest year, c(L) scheme(s1color) ytitle(something sensible)
```